# can not retrieve static fields in solr

Tags: solr

I read about templates in solr and add static field in solr index in topic below but when i add this to my data-config.xml cant retrieve that field
[How would I insert a static value into a field ?](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#How_would_I_insert_a_static_value_into_a_field_.3F)

```
 <pre>
  <dataConfig>   
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expina" user="root" password="root"/>

  <document>
  <entity name="category" query="SELECT * from category">
  <field column="section" template="category"/>
  </entity>
  <entity name="mark" query="SELECT * from mark">
  <field column="section" template="mark"/>
  </entity>
  <entity name="stuffs" query="CALL fetchAllStuffs();" >
  <field column="section" template="stuff"/>
  </entity>
  </document>

  </dataConfig>
  </pre>
```

Comment: Your `data-config.xml` does not indicate which field is static. Can you please explain?

Comment: Also, you would need to add `transformer="TemplateTransformer" ` to the entities that need to use templates.